# django - Ajax Live Search, What Am I Doing Wrong?

Tags: jquery, ajax, django, django-templates, django-views

I'm trying to have a live search feature where as soon as you type something in a search box, the results automatically appear right below. I've been following [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jKSNciGr8kY&t=974s) with no luck. Nothing seems to be happening when I type a query.

Could anybody tell me what I'm doing wrong?

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.list_of_post, name='list_of_post'),
    [...]
    url(r'^search/$', views.search_titles),
]

# this is my blog app views. Original view contains
# url(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls', namespace='blog', app_name='blog')),
```

views.py

```
# Main view that displays all my posts

def list_of_post(request):
    post = Post.objects.filter(status='published')
    categories = Category.objects.all()

    template = 'blog/post/list_of_post.html'

    context = {
        'posts': posts,
        'categories': categories,

        [...]
    }
    return render(request, template, context)

# View that should return my results?

def search_titles(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        search_text = request.POST['search_text']
    else:
        search_text = ''

    classes = Post.objects.filter(title__contains=search_text)

    return render_to_response('blog/ajax_search.html', {'classes': classes})
```

template

```
<h3>Search</h3>
{% csrf_token %}
<input type="text" id="search" name="search"/>
<ul id="search-results">
</ul>
```

ajax_search.html

```
{% if classes %}
        {% for class in classes %}
            <p>{{ class.title }}</p>
        {% endfor %}
{% else %}
    <p>No classes found.</p>
{% endif %}
```

and finally, ajax.js

```
$(function() {

    $('#search').keyup(function() {

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "blog/search/",
            data: {
                'search_text' : $('#search').val(),
                'csrfmiddlewaretoken' : $("input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]").val()
            },
            success: searchSuccess,
            dataType: 'html'
        });
    });
});

function searchSuccess(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
{
    $('#search-results').html(data)
}
```

all my files are loaded up properly, a quick console check confirms ajax.js & jquery being loaded with no errors. When I type anything in my search box, nothing appears below. I have followed the tutorial pretty consistently and I can't see where I might have gone wrong. If anybody could help, it would be appreciated!

Comment: The `url` value of your Ajax call probably needs a leading slash: `url: "/blog/search/"`

Comment: I just tried it, still the same result, nothing shows up when I write anything in my search box.

Comment: can you try with **'search/$'** instead of **'^search/$'**

Comment: tried it, a long a few other variations just to be sure, nothing changed

Comment: Have you isolated where it is going wrong? If you add `alert(data)` to searchSuccess, what do you see?

Comment: Yes you need to do some debugging. Is the Ajax call being made? Is Django receiving it? Is it being routed to the correct view? Is that view returning the correct response? Is the success callback receiving the expected data?

Comment: I'm very inexperienced with jquery, ajax. Where do I need to include the alert(data)?

Comment: from what I can figure out, I don't think the ajax call is being made, since in the chrome tools I see nothing in the network tab, nor in the console tab about any request made

Answer (score 0):

You have two issue :

- You need to return render json in your search_title function.
- And you cannot display data via django template tags when you return
  an ajax request data in your search result template.

Follow this article. This really works
 https://realpython.com/blog/python/django-and-ajax-form-submissions/

Comment: i've looked into that article before. The thing is, I've followed a tutorial on YouTube where he does exactly that and it works. Other people in the comments have reported that it works too. But for some reason, I am doing something wrong and it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

The problem might have occurred in the URL pattern definition. By default, Django parses URLs from top to bottom. So you can change the pattern from

```
urlpatterns = [
url(r'^$', views.list_of_post, name='list_of_post'),
[...]
url(r'^search/$', views.search_titles),]
```

to the below one and try once again. Make sure that there are no URLs before the search that have other patterns and view functions that take arguments from URLs. The preferable position for search URL would be right after the first URL. Please also do cross check the ajax and jquery source file linking in the head section.

```
urlpatterns = [
url(r'^$', views.list_of_post, name='list_of_post'),
url(r'^search/$', views.search_titles),
[...]
]
```